# GetDirectoryName(@"C:\") returns null - why?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does GetDirectoryName return null for C:\?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672236/why-does-getdirectoryname-return-null-for-c)

Step through this and note that 'folder' will be null.
Is there something in the core library that I can use/add to ensure that I can 'get' C:\ as a directory, so that I can later Combine it with another directory? This is important because it  "C:\" is valid data for the requirement I am trying to meet

using System.IO;

```
    string folder = @"C:\";
    folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(folder);
    string folder2 = Path.Combine(folder, "IWantToCombineThisFolderButIGetException");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx):

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.String
>
> Directory information for path, or null if path denotes a root directory or is null.

If you need it to not be null, just coerce the return value to the value you want, like `\`:

```
folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(folder) ?? "\\";
```

Comment: I used your suggestion as well as used combined the 'folder' path with the DirectoryInfo.Root of the folder. Thanks for the pointers

Comment: Actually, GetFullPath(string path) is simpler: