# How to add multiple files in one zip file through the code

Tags: c#, zip

I try to add multiple files into one single zip files using console application in .NET.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string SourcePath1 = @"d:\SRS_9.4.7.25_1033";
            string SourcePath2 = @"d:\sanju2.nuspec";
            string SourcePath1 = @"d:\sanju1.nuspec";
            string DestinationPath = @"d:\Result9.zip";
            if (File.Exists(DestinationPath))
            {
                File.Delete(DestinationPath);
            }
            string[] Files = { SourcePath1, SourcePath2 };
            foreach (string variableName in Files)
            {

                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(variableName, DestinationPath);

            }
            Console.WriteLine(DestinationPath);

        }
    }
}
```

I got this error message...

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'd:\sanju1.nuspec'.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption) at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.DoCreateFromDirectory(String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName, Nullable`1 compressionLevel, Boolean includeBaseDirectory, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName)
at ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\sanjeev_kushvaha\source\repos\ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip\ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip\Program.cs:line 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In this code, I added multiple files from various location of machine into a specific location.**

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Compression;
    namespace ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip
    {
       internal class Program
       {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
           
                Console.WriteLine("..........Convert multiple files into a zip file...........");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                string zipPath = @"d:\result" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff") + ".zip";

                using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the 1st file path, Which you want to add: ");
                        string sourcePath1 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the 2st file path, Which you want to add: ");
                        string sourcePath2 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the 3st file path, Which you want to add: ");
                        string sourcePath3 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the 4st file path, Which you want to add: ");
                        string sourcePath4 = Console.ReadLine();
                        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(sourcePath1, "file1.txt");
                        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(sourcePath2, "file2.txt");
                        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(sourcePath3, "file1.txt");
                        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(sourcePath4, "sanju1.nupkg");

                  
                    }
                    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirEx)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Directory not found: " + dirEx.Message);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Zip file path is " + zipPath + " .");     

        }

    }
}
```

In this problem, First install System.IO.Compression.ZipFile from NuGet package manager then I used ZipArchive method which is present in System.IO.Compression. zipPath is path where I want to store our zip file. ZipArchiveMode.Create is basically showing what I want do with zip file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your directory exist with `Directory.Exists(string path)`

Also, `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` require at first argument the directory where your files that you want to zip are located and not the filename.

Here is your code fixed.

```
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string BaseDirectory = @"D:\StackOverflow\SO-questions_74915327\";
            string FilesSourceDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, "files");
            //Define the DestinationDirectory. We can include the file name also but if we use Path.GetDirectoryName when we need to check (and create) the directory we can obtain null if the path is egal to the root.
            //See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672236/why-does-getdirectoryname-return-null-for-c
            string DestinationDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, @"output\");
            string DestinationFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(DestinationDirectory, "zipfile.zip");
            //check if directory exist, if not then show a msg and return;
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(FilesSourceDirectory))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, this directory " + BaseDirectory + " doesnt exist");
                return;
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(DestinationDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationDirectory);
            }
            else
            {
                //delete the file if exist
                if (File.Exists(DestinationFileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(DestinationFileName);
                }
            }
            //check if the directory is empty, dont create a empty zip file.
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(FilesSourceDirectory);
            if (files.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the FilesSourceDirectory " + FilesSourceDirectory + " doest contain any files");
                return;
            }
            //ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory accept a directory who contains your files and as second argument the FullPath output
            //Check if FilesSourceDirectory is a directory ! Optional
            FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(FilesSourceDirectory);
            if (!attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory)) {
                Console.WriteLine("FilesSourceDirectory is a file path and not a directory !");
                return;
            }
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(FilesSourceDirectory, DestinationFileName);
            Console.WriteLine("Final DestinationPath :" + DestinationFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit :** Following your comment, i created a new version of the code by putting your values in it and keeping your initial way of doing things (manually defining the files to compress instead of providing a folder directly as in my previous code).
In this new version, we must move the files to a new temporary folder to be able to give it as an argument to `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`

```
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string BaseDirectory = @"D:\";
            List<string> FilesToZip = new List<string>
            {
                "sanju2.nuspec",//D:\sanju2.nuspec
                "sanju1.nuspec"//D:\sanju1.nuspec
            };
            //check if FilesToZip is empty (doest contain any files)
            if (FilesToZip.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You need to add files inside FilesToZip");
                return;
            }
            //create inside the temp directory a new folder call "ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip"
            string TempDirectory = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "ConvertMultipleFilesIntoZip");
            if (!Directory.Exists(TempDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(TempDirectory);
            }
            //move each files in FilesToZip to this folder
            foreach (string File in FilesToZip)
            {
                string OriginFilePath = Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, File);
                string TempFilePath = Path.Combine(TempDirectory, File);
                //check if the file exist in the source dir
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(OriginFilePath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the file " + File + " doesnt exist in this directory : " + OriginFilePath);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Copy(OriginFilePath, TempFilePath, true);
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAE)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error, you dont have access to this folder / file : " + TempFilePath);
                        Console.WriteLine(UAE.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error on copy : " + ex.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            string DestinationFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, "Result9.zip"); //should be D:\Result9.zip
            if (File.Exists(DestinationFileName))
            {
                File.Delete(DestinationFileName);
            }

            //check if the directory is empty.
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(TempDirectory);
            if (files.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error, the FilesSourceDirectory " + TempDirectory + " doest contain any files");
                return;
            }
            //ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory accept a directory who contains your files and as second argument the FullPath output
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(TempDirectory, DestinationFileName);
            //try clean / remove TempDirectory
            try
            {
                System.IO.Directory.Delete(TempDirectory, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Impossible to delete temp files in " + TempDirectory + "\n" + ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Final DestinationPath :" + DestinationFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi SioGabx, I need to add multiple files into zip. In this code, I give right path but I got the same error.

Comment: Can you send me your code again by making a new "edit" section in your question to check if everything is correct?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a new version of the code a bit closer to what you originally had

Comment: I used another method to solve this problem. I will put in answer box so you will see their.